# Check an array of email addresses with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, indexof

I am using jQuery and would like to check if an email address is hosted at a free email service domain (i.e. Yahoo, gmail, hotmail, etc).

The code below does it, but unfortunately I do not know the syntax enough to put domain names in an array and now I can check (without additional if statements) if the email is, in this case, hosted by Yahoo only.

Is there anything like `if ($(this).val().indexOf("yahoo.com && gmail.com && hotmail.com && ... ") != -1)` ?

Here is the script:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#bemail').click(
        function(e){
            e.preventDefault;
            if ($(this).val().indexOf("Business email is required") != -1) {
            $('#bemail').val("");
            }
    });

    $('#bemail').blur(function() {
        if ($(this).val().indexOf("yahoo.com") != -1)
        {
            $(this).val("Business email is required");
        }

    });

});
</script>
```

Thanks.

Comment: isolate the domain checking code from the form input data extraction, it'll make your code easier and make it non-jQuery specific

Answer (score 2):

You can create an array of email services, then check your value to see if it equals any of the emails you've listed. You'd do this by using a for loop to compare each of the values in the array against the value of the input. You would do something like this:

```
var freeServices = ["yahoo.com", "gmail.com"];

$('#bemail').blur(function() {
    for(var i = 0; len = freeServices.length; i<len; i++) {
        if ($(this).val().indexOf(freeServices[i]) != -1) {
            $(this).val("Business email is required");
        }
    }
});
```

Add the email services to the array as needed, preserving syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Eliot, thank you for the solution. Copy-pasted code didn't work (I don't know why, maybe because len wasn't declared, although I tried that) so I fixed it a bit for those like me, who don't know Javascript well... Here is the code that works on my page:

```
$('#bemail').blur(function() {
var freeServices = ["yahoo.com","gmail.com","hotmail.com"];

    for(var i = 0; i < freeServices.length; i++)
    {
        if ($(this).val().indexOf(freeServices[i]) != -1)
        {
            $(this).val("Business email is required");
        }
    }
});
```